# In Rails Create or Update an element in frontend in real time, triggered on pre set intervals

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, frontend, real-time

I have a list of events, with a start time and end time, they are displayed as a grid, on index action.
What I want is to display a dynamic status next to each event

- ‘Upcoming’, if start time > now
- ‘Live’ of start time < now && end time > now
- ‘Offline’ if end time < now.

I also want to show a popup alert for some events when they go live.

I can set the status first time when page is loaded, but how to change the status if user is on the page and page isn’t reloaded or refreshed.
I’m looking for a solution that can be easily implemented with a rails 5 app, and provides a good user experince.

Comment: You'll probably need to use javascript for that. Personally, I would store time in the DOM and set interval which would find all <time> elements, parse datetime attribute and change inner text using rules as you described. You could also include popup as well, just you'll need to store state somewhere so it wouldn't appear multiple times when event goes live.

Comment: @RolandasBarysas I had something similar in mind, where I have a list of all times and I check every if something needs to be changed every X minutes, but If I have several things that need changed every minute, i think it becomes very inefficient to do it that way. I would like something like we see when a new email is received in gmail when inbox is open.

Comment: Unless you're planning of having thousands of events in a single page, I don't see how it's inefficient. You could do polling to backend and refresh template that way, but there's no point if data does not need an update.